# There are a weird line in the html with id "text". What is this?

Tags: html, drupal-7

[image]

What is this in the html?

I use Drupal 7, firefox.
In chrome there is no that line in html but the space is there in the site.
Tooltip: text node with only empty characters

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you have this "icon" in another web browser? What if you place your cursor over it? Do you get a tooltip?